# 1942 Battle Ship Bombardment

Tags: axis-and-allies

When my battleship does a bombardment, can the battleship stay on the board for the remainder of the turn and get the 2 hit advantage.

I.e.

My battleship comes in with a transport and some infantry men. The battleship does a bombardment. After my attack, I defend. If the defending player gets a hit, can I allocate that hit to my battleship?

Answer (score 1):

No - land units can never hit a naval unit in any event. Plus, the only purpose of a battleship during an amphibious assault is to conduct a shore bombardment. Once completed, the battleship is removed from the battle-board and is no longer part of the combat.